# Four point probe method under liquid nitrogen

Tags: experimental-physics, superconductivity

I was trying to measure the resistivity of the YBCO superconductor (but not like a resistivity- T diagram, but only at liquid nitrogen boiling point), so I needed to put the sample in thermal contact with liquid nitrogen, my question is if the point probes are also in contact with liquid nitrogen, does it affect the measurement? because I got some weird data, the voltage was decreasing as I used more current to obtain the resistivity and that would mean that resistivity is a function of the applied current or that the low current I was barely increasing changed its temperature.

Comment: Use short current pulses to separate thermal effects from actual non-ohmic behavior.

Comment: I think that you need to provide a diagram of the setup and circuit you are using for the measurements. There may be some subtleties involved here. For example, if you are measuring the resistance of a sample at low temperature using an instrument which is presumably at room temperature, there will be thermoelectric voltages induced in the measurement wires themselves. That's why AC or alternating DC measurements are usually performed on low temperature samples.

Comment: So do I need an instrumental amplifier to get rid of those thermoelectric voltages?